# Launch macOS shortkeys in Processing on visual button

Tags: lua, processing

In Processing, I'm building a simple buttons interface. And the idea is that when you click on a button in the sketch. A text snippet from a different macOS application will launch a text snippet box.

At the moment, this text snippet box will be launched if I type a word in an email. So let's say I type (sample-a) in the email, and this will open a text snippet box that I have set up with this application.

But I want to trigger (sample-a) on a button click in Processing and not have to type this word in the email.

I searched the internet and looked at io.popen, os.execute and launch. But I wondered what the best way is to trigger a macOS "word" from Processing on a button click? Maybe do something with an echo command?

I hope someone can give me some tips or have an example code to create this function?

*added updated code:

```
// Import library for textfields
import g4p_controls.*;

GTextField txf1;
String sample;

boolean background = true;
// Button setup
final int btnX = 100;
final int btnY = 100;
final int btnW = 200;
final int btnH = 200;

public void setup() {
  size(400, 600);
  background(209, 209, 209);

  // Button
  rect(btnX, btnY, btnW, btnH);

  // Textfield setup
  txf1 = new GTextField(this, 100, 400, 200, 20);
}

public void draw() {

  if (keyPressed && key == ENTER) {
  }
}

public void handleTextEvents(GEditableTextControl textcontrol, GEvent event) {
  if (txf1 == textcontrol && event == GEvent.ENTERED) {
    sample = txf1.getText();
  }
}

// Button trigger
void mousePressed() {
  if (mouseX >= btnX && mouseX <= btnX + btnW && mouseY >= btnY && mouseY <= btnY + btnH) {
    println("button clicked");
    exec("open", "/Applications/TextExpander.app");
    txf1.setText("sample");
  }
}
```

New code for button interface with ControlP5 and Robot Class

```
import controlP5.*;

import java.awt.AWTException;
import java.awt.Robot;
import java.awt.event.KeyEvent;


boolean background = true;

// Robot function
Robot robot;
String  keyString="template-1";

Robot1 robot1;
String  keyString="template-2";

ControlP5 gui;

void setup() {
  size(1440, 900);


  gui = new ControlP5(this);

  //Add a Button
  gui.addButton("Template 1")
    .setPosition(50, 50)
    .setSize(100, 100)
    .setValue(0)
    .activateBy(ControlP5.RELEASE);
  ;

  gui.addButton("Template 2")
    .setPosition(200, 50)
    .setSize(100, 100)
    .setValue(0)
    .activateBy(ControlP5.RELEASE);
  ;

  // Robot function
  try {
    robot = new Robot();
    robot1 = new Robot1();
  }
  catch (AWTException ex) {
    System.out.println(ex.getMessage());
  }
  frameRate(1);
  // Robot function
}

public void Template1(int value) {
  println("Template 1 Button pressed");
  sendKeys(robot, keyString);
}

public void Template2(int value) {
  println("Template 2 Button pressed");
  sendKeys(robot1, keyString);
}

public void controlEvent(ControlEvent theEvent) {
}

// Robot function for Template 1
void sendKeys(Robot robot, String keys) {
  for (char c : keys.toCharArray()) {
    int keyCode = KeyEvent.getExtendedKeyCodeForChar(c);
    if (KeyEvent.CHAR_UNDEFINED == keyCode) {
      throw new RuntimeException(
        "Key code not found for character '" + c + "'");
    }
    robot.keyPress(keyCode);
    robot.delay(100);
    robot.keyRelease(keyCode);
    robot.delay(100);
    noLoop();
  }
}

// Robot function for Template 2
void sendKeys(Robot1 robot1, String keys) {
  for (char c : keys.toCharArray()) {
    int keyCode = KeyEvent.getExtendedKeyCodeForChar(c);
    if (KeyEvent.CHAR_UNDEFINED == keyCode) {
      throw new RuntimeException(
        "Key code not found for character '" + c + "'");
    }
    robot1.keyPress(keyCode);
    robot1.delay(100);
    robot1.keyRelease(keyCode);
    robot1.delay(100);
    noLoop();
  }
}

void draw() {
}
```

Comment: exec() might do what you are trying to achieve.

Comment: @apodidae Thanks for the tip! Do you maybe also know which command I should use to write/type/execute the word? 

This is already working on macOS: exec("/usr/bin/say","(sample-a)");

Comment: I'm trying some commands from this overview website:

https://ss64.com/osx/

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean by write/type/execute the word?  To open an app you would use something like Process proc = exec("open", "/Applications/myApp.app");  If you can come up with a simple demo I'll try to help you get it working.

Comment: @apodidae, I appreciate your help! I'm still learning and improving my Processing/Lua knowledge. I will probably enhance the button function also, but for now, it's working for me to test things.

Comment: boolean background = true;

void setup(){
  size(400,400);
}

void draw(){
  rect(100,100,200,200);
}

boolean isMouseOver(int x, int y, int w, int h){
  if(mouseX >= x && mouseX <= x + w && mouseY >= y && mouseY <= y + h){
    return  true;
  }
  return false;
}

Comment: void mousePressed(){
  if(isMouseOver(width/2,height/2,100,100) == true){
    println("button clicked");
    
    //  Process proc = I'm doing more research on this
    
  exec("open", "/Applications/TextExpander.app");
    
   // name of the TextExpander abbreviation / shortcut = "(sample-a)"
   // code that fire the word "(sample-a)" so that a TextExpander snippet will popup
  }
}

Comment: You may add your code to your original post by editing it and then copy/pasting your source code in between two sets of three grave characters on separate lines, eg (new line)\```your code on multiple lines(new line)\```.  If using the Processing IDE it also helps to use Edit/AutoFormat first so that it will look nicer.

Comment: Nice edit.  Does your app launch when the button is hit?

Answer (score 0):

Here is your source code as posted in the comments:

```
boolean background = true;

void setup() {
  size(400, 400);
}

void draw() {
  rect(100, 100, 200, 200);
}

boolean isMouseOver(int x, int y, int w, int h) {
  if (mouseX >= x && mouseX <= x + w && mouseY >= y && mouseY <= y + h) {
    return true;
  }
  return false;
}

void mousePressed() {
 // if (isMouseOver(width/2, height/2, 100, 100) == true){ 
 if (isMouseOver(100, 100, 200, 200) == true) {   
    println("button clicked");
    // Process proc = I'm doing more research on this exec("open", "/Applications/TextExpander.app");
    // name of the TextExpander abbreviation / shortcut = "(sample-a)"
    // code that fire the word "(sample-a)" so that a TextExpander snippet will popup
  }
}
```

As written there is a problem with mousePressed(); it will only pick up a button click toward the bottom of the button.  Clicks at the top do nothing.  That's due to an error in the line if(isMouseOver()== true) because the parameters are incorrect; they should be the same as the parameters that you used to create the rect initially, ie (100,100,200,200).

**Alternate revision which shortens the code by obviating the function isMouseOver().**  Rectangle coordinates are made constants so that if you want to change the size of the button later you only will have to change the parameter once instead of finding multiple occurrences in your code. Your initial version will certainly work as is, but I am only showing you a possible way to improve it.  As you continue to experiment we can edit this post to reflect changes.  Keep on experimenting and you should hopefully achieve your goal.

```
boolean background = true;

final int btnX = 100;
final int btnY = 100;
final int btnW = 200;
final int btnH = 200;

void setup() {
  size(400, 400);
  rect(btnX, btnY, btnW, btnH);
}

void draw() {
}

void mousePressed() {
  if (mouseX >= btnX && mouseX <= btnX + btnW && mouseY >= btnY && mouseY <= btnY + btnH) {
    println("button clicked");
    // Process proc = I'm doing more research on this exec("open", "/Applications/TextExpander.app");
    // name of the TextExpander abbreviation / shortcut = "(sample-a)"
    // code that fire the word "(sample-a)" so that a TextExpander snippet will popup
  }
}
```

**Robot revision:**

You don't need two robots; one will suffice.  Likewise you don't need two sendKeys() function.  Use one robot and send it a different string depending on which button is pressed.  Whatever name is used for the button, that string is also used to called a corresponding function and the two must match precisely. That is, if you title the button 'template_1' then the function needs to be 'template_1()' also.

```
import controlP5.*;
import java.awt.AWTException;
import java.awt.Robot;
import java.awt.event.KeyEvent;

Robot robot;
ControlP5 gui;

String  keyString = "template-1";
String  keyString2 = "template-2";

void setup() {
  size(350, 250);
  gui = new ControlP5(this);
// Function that's called must match the button title.
  gui.addButton("Template_1")
    .setPosition(50, 50)
    .setSize(100, 100)
    .activateBy(ControlP5.RELEASE);
  ;

  gui.addButton("Template_2")
    .setPosition(200, 50)
    .setSize(100, 100)
    .activateBy(ControlP5.RELEASE);
  ;

  try {
    robot = new Robot();
  } catch (AWTException ex) {
    System.out.println(ex.getMessage());
  }
}

void Template_1() {
  println("Template 1 Button pressed");
  sendKeys(keyString);
}

void Template_2() {
  println("Template 2 Button pressed");
  sendKeys(keyString2);
}

public void controlEvent(ControlEvent evnt) {
  println(evnt);
}

void sendKeys(String keys) {
  println("sendKeys fired.");
  delay(3000); // Give user some time to set cursor
  for (char c : keys.toCharArray()) {
    println(c);
    int keyCode = KeyEvent.getExtendedKeyCodeForChar(c);
    if (KeyEvent.CHAR_UNDEFINED == keyCode) {
      throw new RuntimeException(
        "Key code not found for character '" + c + "'");
    }
    robot.keyPress(keyCode);
    robot.delay(100);
    robot.keyRelease(keyCode);
    robot.delay(100);
  }
}

void draw() {
}
```

Comment: Thank you so much for giving feedback on the button function! I also saw that there was a problem with the hit points. 

(I have added my current code to the first post.)

I thought that maybe it's possible to make Processing "type" a word in a text field on a button pressed and that this will launch the TextExpander snippet?

The snippet word will be displayed in the text field when you click the button. But this does not (yet) launch the snippet. If I type the word myself in the textfield, then it will work. Maybe there's an event or something else that I should use to make this work?

Comment: Does your app launch?  You could try a second exec() command, eg exec("command","sample-a") just beneath the first exec().  Put a println("text entered") in the event handler so we can tell when it is fired.  Could also try putting the second exec("command", enteredTextString) in the handler so that user could get template of choice.

Comment: Yes, the app launch with this code:
exec("open", "/Applications/TextExpander.app");

But if I try to trigger the snippet itself with:
exec("command" , "sample-a");
Then that is not working, I also tried some different things like:

exec("open", "/Applications/TextExpander.app" + "command", "sample-a");

I'm probably overlooking something.

Comment: Unfortunately I can't do any testing here.  How do you normally trigger 'sample-a', eg is it a menu item?  Do you have code to trigger it from the command line in Terminal?  May have to use a script.

Comment: Currently, I just type the word "sample-a" on the keyword in an email or in TextEdit. And it will pop up a TextExpander snippet and I select something's in the snippet. Place my cursor back in the email and click on OK in the snippet. And the snippet will be inserted in the email.

TextExpander has access to my OS via Accessibility under Security & Privacy on macOS.

There's also some information here, but I'm uncertain if it's still fully works:

https://textexpander.com/learn/using/snippets/scripting-textexpander/applescript-shellscript

Comment: If TextExpander can be linked to an e-mail app or TextEdit, then you should be able to link it to a Processing app.  How did you train it to accept TextEdit input, for example?

Comment: At the moment it's not really linked to an application. In TextExpander I can give every template snippet an Abbreviation. For example, sample-a. I can type "sample-a" in all text box/text fields of every software on my Mac. So in an email, website text field or even in this add comment field on stack overflow.

Comment: So can you type 'sample-a' into your Processing text field and get a response?

Comment: Yes. If I now type sample-a in a Processing text field, the TextExpander snippet will launch. So that's already great:)

But it's not fully working. If I select something in the snippet and put my mouse cursor back to a TextEdit.app file and click OK in the TextExpander snippet, the snippet is not inserted into the TextEdit.app file. It's the same for if I want to add the snippet back to the Processing text field. 

I think the snippet is copied to the macOS clipboard, but never inserted.

Comment: If it's on the clipboard, cmd-v should insert it.

Comment: cmd-v (copy/past) is not working. I'm uncertain if it's sent to a clipboard or if the snippet is just lost. (it was more to describe the experience)

Comment: I'm excited to tell you that I am a step further in my project. With the Java Robot class, I now simulate the text command if it's typed on the keyboard. Soon I will post an update on this tread with some code so that we can answer the question. Thanks so much for your help!

Comment: please see the added code in my first post. I'm trying to use ControlP5 and Robot Class to make the interface. The Template-1 button is working. But I would like to add many more buttons, and I was wondering what the best way to add many buttons with their own string is? 

Maybe there's a way to write something that will add all the buttons + strings to the function so that I don't need to write a new function for every button?